# "ApplicationError: Solver (ipopt) did not exit normally" after compiling and installing ipopt by myself

Tags: anaconda, spyder, mingw-w64, pyomo, ipopt

I've been trying to install/compile `ipopt` in my Windows computer and so far I am not having any progress. I am mostly following the instructions listed here: `https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/INSTALL`. I downloaded MSYS2 MinGW specifically for this purpose.

As dependencies I have downloaded the following

- OpenBLAS;
- blis;
- ThirdParty-ASL;
- ThirdParty-HSL (with the HSL library solvers which I need);
- ThirdParty-Mumps;

In the end, I get `ipopt.exe` in the `C:\msys64\home\me\Ipopt\src\Apps\AmplSolver` folder. But there is also another `ipopt.exe` in the `C:\msys64\home\me\Ipopt\src\Apps\AmplSolver\.libs` folder, so I tried to make use of both.

I am using Anaconda Navigator and Pyomo to see whether my `ipopt.exe` works, so I put the resulting `ipopt.exe` in the `Anaconda\envs\myenv\Library\bin` folder. However, the ipopt executable that I got gives me errors. One of them gives me an error related to `libipoptamplinterface-3.dll`. When I run the below Python script using Spyder:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
model.nVars = pyo.Param(initialize=4)
model.N = pyo.RangeSet(model.nVars)
model.x = pyo.Var(model.N, within=pyo.Binary)
model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr=pyo.summation(model.x))
model.cuts = pyo.ConstraintList()
opt = SolverFactory('ipopt')
opt.solve(model) 

# Iterate, adding a cut to exclude the previously found solution
for i in range(5):
   expr = 0
   for j in model.x:
       if pyo.value(model.x[j]) < 0.5:
           expr += model.x[j]
       else:
           expr += (1 - model.x[j])
   model.cuts.add( expr >= 1 )
   results = opt.solve(model)
   print ("\n===== iteration",i)
   model.display()
```

I get errors such as this:

```
ERROR: Solver (ipopt) returned non-zero return code (127)
ApplicationError: Solver (ipopt) did not exit normally
```

I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Maybe first check whether the Ipopt binary works when just from the command line.
That is, do a `make test` after `make`.
Also don't forget to do a `make install`.
Instead of copying the Ipopt binary (and the DLLs it requires) around, maybe just put the path to the Ipopt installation into your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Your model is a MILP type of optimization however the ipopt solver is not for this purpose use glpk solver instead of that